# nested resources with filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this is my house model

```
has_many :taggings
has_many :tags, through: :taggings

def self.tagged_with(name)
    Tag.find_by_name!(name).houses
 end

end
```

this is my house controller

```
    def index
        if params[:tag]
          @houses = House.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    end
end
```

view:

```
- @houses.each do |house|
ect
```

This works fine...this filters out the houses with the current tag, like this /house/tag/tagname

But i implemented a nested resources so i need to change my view to this.

```
- @regions.each do |region|
      - region.houses.find_all do |house|
```

How can i use the filter tag in the new view? I thought this

```
- @regions.each do |region|
      - region.houses.find_tagged_with(params[:tags]) do |house|
```

but this wil not work...please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not filter it the other way around? That is, instead of getting all the houses for a region and filtering it by tag, get all the houses for a tag and filter it by region:

```
def index
  @regions = Region.all # or whatever
  @houses = House.tagged_with(params[:tag])

  @regions.each do |region|
    @houses.where(region_id: region.id).each do |house|
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not work becoz the tagged_with is defined in the class House and is not callable on the instance or any collection. The region.houses is an array (assuming region has_many houses) so it won't work on it. One way to do this is to use ActiveRecord::Relation

```
@regions.each do |region|
 - region.houses.where(:name => params[:tag).each do |house|
```

Refer to Rails guide to know more about it...

Comment: thanks Aditya for the quick reply!. I test you're your solution but my output is null. I think because the tags is in an another table.

class House < ActiveRecord::Base
 extend FriendlyId
 has_many :taggings
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :houses, through: :taggings
end

How can i solve this?